# Can I remove D: partition or recovery partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, lenovo-laptop

I bought lenovo G510 laptop about 2 years ago.

These are the partitions that I have on my computer (I haven't changed any anything):

1000 MB - healthy, recovery partition

260 MB - healthy, system EFI partition

1000 MB - OEM partition

424 GB - Windows parition (C:/) (I have also my files on this partition)

25 GB - Lenovo parition (D:/) with folders "Drivers" and "Applications" on it.

14 GB - recovery partition.

[image: Screen of my disk management]

Now, I want to install Ubuntu on my computer and I also want to have Windows.

Now, I can't modify my C:/ partition because I have my files on it, which I don't want to loose. I can't also shrink that partition for some reason in Windows Disk Manager. Now, the best thing that I would like to do is to remove that D:/ parition (25 GB) or recovery partition (14 GB) and install Ubuntu on one of those partitions. So I followed this instruction to create recovery disk on my USB storage: https://support.lenovo.com/gb/pl/solutions/ht080887 to move this recovery parition to my USB and to be able to remove it after so that I can install ubuntu on this partition. And I did that, but at the end of creating recovery disk on my USB storage, I didn't have any option to remove recovery partition, I don't know why - apparently I can't do this for some reason.

Now I have two questions:

1. Can I remove D:/ parition with the Drivers folder on it or something bad will happen if I do that? (I plan to move the Drivers and Application folder somewehere else obviosuly) Or can I at least shrink this partition (this would be enough for me)?
2. Can I remove the recovery partition using Diskpart (because I can't do it using Windows standard partition manager, I don't have option for that for some reason) or something bad will happen?

If I remember correctly at the beginning I had Windows 8, but I updated to Windows 10, if this information is needed for some reason.

Comment: What is the OEM partition? I suggest you to move all your data from C:/ to D:/, Srink C:/ at least 50GB and extend D:/. If there is no important data you may delete recovery partition. Provide a screenshot of disk management.

Comment: How can I move my data from C to D if D has only 25 GB and I have about 200 GB on C? I can't shrink C - I have no option for that in disk management. I provided the screenshot.

Comment: Move one by one. With consecutive shrink and extend processes. What are those 1000MB hidden partitions?

Answer (score 0):

@Damian, according to your situation,

1. the best choice for you is to just shrink some space form C to create partition for installing Ubuntu. You can rely on a third party partition software to do so since disk management are unavailable.
2. Unless you can't shrink C anyway, you can insert another disk into your computer to install Ubuntu.
3. The third choice is to move all things on D partition to C and install Ubuntu on D partition but 25 GB is not enough for a system to run in the long term.
4. the final choice is to delete recovery partition for installing Ubuntu. You may unhide it to be able to delete it. Also, 14 GB is not enough for a system to run in the long term. Anyhow, you can delete the recovery partition since it will only restore to Windows 8, the factory default OS, even if you have upgraded to win10.

All above operations can be done by a common third party software. Hope you can solve your problem by one of the several ways above!

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Can I remove D:/ parition with the Drivers folder on it or something bad will happen if I do that? (I plan to move the Drivers and Application folder somewehere else obviosuly) Or can I at least shrink this partition (this would be enough for me)?

Yes, copy all data but keep it safe you will need them or as a better option shrink **C** drive you can easily do it with live ubuntu and GParted.

Question 2: Can I remove the recovery partition using Diskpart (because I can't do it using Windows standard partition manager, I don't have option for that for some reason) or something bad will happen?

Don't do it you will need it in future if you lost your windows but if you want to do it so try GParted from ubuntu live.

> As per my opinion just shrink 50 or 100 GB from your C drive it will
>   be fine.

Comment: But will I loose my data if I shrink C drive with Ubuntu GParted?

Comment: @Damian, You can shrink drive without worrying about data loss but first check tutorials for it.